# How can I make a web app turn properly on all mobile devices?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, web-applications, orientation

I am working on a mobile web app. The app in portrait mode must have a different look then in landscape. This is why I wrote the following code:

```
function orientation(){
    if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
        $('.ui-page').removeClass("pageL").addClass("pageP");
        $(window).resize();
        $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'height=device-height,width=400,user-scalable=no')
        $(window).resize();
        alert('portrait');
    } else {
        $('.ui-page').removeClass("pageP").addClass("pageL");
        $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1');
        $(window).resize();         
        $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'height=device-height,width=960,user-scalable=no');
        $(window).resize();
        alert('landscape');
    };
};  

var supportsOrientationChange = "onorientationchange" in window,
orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? "orientationchange" : "resize";

window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {
    orientation();
}, false);
```

Everything works in chrome on my Android tablet, but is doesn't on the iPad and the default browser on my Android. In the default Android browser the problem is when I load the page for example in portrait and turn the tablet 90 degrees it executes the function again but still says he's is portrait. On the iPad everything works but won't zoom out again when I turn it to landscape. The problem on the iPad has probably something to do with the disabled resize function on the iPad, but I can't solve it.

I use innerHeight & Width because some Android devices see landscape as 0 degrees and some see portrait as 0.

Comment: You really should look into responsive web design. This is a problem that's been solved in better ways, and frankly, you need not solve it all over again.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of browsing around on stackoverflow I managed to make this code:

```
function orientation() {
  var content_width, screen_dimension;

  if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
    // portrait
    $('.ui-page').removeClass("pageL").addClass("pageP");
    content_width = 400;        
    if(screen.width < screen.height){screen_dimension = screen.width * 0.9}
    else{screen_dimension = screen.height * 0.9}
  } else{
    // landscape
    $('.ui-page').removeClass("pageP").addClass("pageL");
    content_width = 960;
    if(screen.width > screen.height){screen_dimension = screen.width}
    else{screen_dimension = screen.height}
  }

  var viewport_scale = screen_dimension / content_width;

  // resize viewport
  $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content',
    'height=device-height, width=' + content_width + ',' +
    'minimum-scale=' + viewport_scale + ', maximum-scale=' + viewport_scale);
}

var supportsOrientationChange = "orientationchange" in window,
orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? "orientationchange" : "resize";

window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {
    orientation()
}, false);

$(document).bind("pageinit",function(){
    orientation()
}).trigger('pageinit');
```

This time almost everything works on every browser I tested (Android & iOS). The only problem left is on iOS. When you click on an input field, the orientation magically changes.